# How to append text like in <p> one on right side and the other one left side

Tags: node.js, ajax

I m using ajax with ejs and backend nodejs. What i am getting is the conversation from mongoose and i want to show it to ejs using ajax. What i want is to display if result on right side and else result on left side.

```
$.get('http://localhost:3001/blog/getChat/',
                function(messageArray) {
                    // alert("Hello" + messageArray[5].message)
                    for (i = 0; i < messageArray.length; i++) {

                        if (messageArray[i].user === userName_) {
                            $('#date').append($('<p>').html(messageArray[i].message)).css({
                                "text-align": "right"
                            });

                        } else {
                            if (messageArray[i].user != userName_) {
                                $('#messages').append($('<p>').html(messageArray[i].message)).css({
                                    "text-align": "left"
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }

                });
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow - if you want to improve on your question skills you can also check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending once to `$('#date')` and once to `$('#messages')`. Perhaps that is a simple typo and it should be as below instead?

```
if (messageArray[i].user === userName_) {
    $('#messages').append($('<p>').html(messageArray[i].message)).css({
        "text-align": "right"
    });
```

Comment: actually that's a typo mistake i have used id #messages in if else